Net use /delete says connection not found, but Test-Path returns true
For context, I need to check if a network drive exists. If it exists then no action, if it doesn't exist need to map it
The problem, Powershell Test-Path is returning true but when I try to delete the path it says it does not exist
I think there may be another user that has it mapped? Not sure how I can check if the current user has it mapped
> net use /delete "\\server\MyShare"
The network connection could not be found.

> Test-Path "\\server\MyShare"
True

>[System.IO.Directory]::Exists('\\server\MyShare')
True

>net use
No results

>Get-PSDrive
No results


Why are you trying to /DELETE the network drive by the UNC name? Why not use the drive letter? NET USE /DELETE T:

Potential conflict if another drive is added, felt it was safer to fully qualify

I think you have a misconception here. As long as the share exists on the network, Test-Path will return true (as it simply checks whether the path is valid, it's not related to any special network share functions at all), regardless whether the share is mapped to a drive letter or not. After all, you don't need to use any drive letter mapping to use a share, you can just use the UNC path directly. The driver letter mapping is used just for convenience and to make it work with applications that don't support UNC paths.

Hmm interesting, is that the same for Get-PSDrive, or does that actually show currently mapped drives?

I think @CherryDT is pointing you in the right direction. Get-PSDrive shows DRIVE names. A UNC path is a SHARE name. The output of Get-PSDrive has a drive named "C" which is used as the C: drive. The environment variables are seen on the Env: drive.

You should be able to use Get-PSDrive to get the drives and check if DisplayRoot of any of the results matches your share.
IF((Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).DisplayRoot -eq '\\server\MyShare') {
   Write-Host 'Network share was found!'
}
else {
   Write-Host 'ERROR: Missing network drive'
}

NOTE: It is possible to have the drive mapped, but not available for some reason.  I had a drive mapped with a different password than the current user, and it had become unavailable because the computer was in sleep mode earlier.  In this case, the above Get-PSDrive statement returned false.  For this reason, if Get-PSDrive fails to find the drive, you may want to remove the share, just in case it exist and is dead, prior to mapping the share.

I think this might be the case, running (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).DisplayRoot doesn't return the share I'm looking for :(
You mention removing the share, but the problem is I can't with /delete, if there's another method?
